# Add Application name to Facebook post

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a web application using Facebook JS api, where user can post using my application. So i want to display my application name under facebook page post title name.

**Image Below**

[image: Application Post Image]

Code:

```
 FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
              'post',
              {   method: 'share',message:TEXTING, caption: 'bitSoft', access_token: TOKEN}
              ,function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                   if(response.id) {

                            console.log(response);               

                  }
              });
```

So please help how could i get this result.

Comment: What is `Social Pixe` ? ... is application name or is different name according to you

Comment: Different name, i have "bitSoft"

Comment: Is it possible to get this result from this code. Which i am using.

Comment: [fb developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed) see options available